Format timer.elapsed for write-host
$timer = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
Start-Sleep -Second 83
$timer.stop
$elapsed=$timer.elapsed
Write-Host $elapsed                                 < Works, but not shown in desired format
Write-Host $elapsed.ToString("DD:HH:MM:SS")         < Overload error on .ToString and Argument count:"1"
Write-Host $($elapsed).ToString("DD:HH:MM:SS")      < Overload error on .ToString and Argument count:"1"


I cannot get the elapsed time to output in the desired format ("DD:HH:MM:SS"; 2 digit days, hours, minutes and seconds).  I've found quite a bit about formatting dates/times directly from Get-Date, and some even claim to show or calculate differences between a start and end time.  But I keep getting Overload errors on any attempt to enforce formatting.

The format strings for a TimeSpan are a bit different from the format strings of DateTime. See Custom TimeSpan format strings.
The format string is all lower case and requires escaping on ::
$timer.Elapsed.ToString('dd\:hh\:mm\:ss')

As an aside, $timer.Stop will get you the method overload definitions; if you want to invoke the method, you have to add () to it:
$timer.Stop()


@NewbieBAT there is no Year and Months available for the format string. You can use .ToString('dd\ \D\a\y\s\ hh\:mm\:ss') for example. No yyyy or MM available for this type. Read the documentation.

Sorry - figured it out and tried to delete question so you weren't bothered, but you answered too quickly :).  I've tried to find comprehensive document ion, but can't.  Do you know where I can find that?  I've had to depend on Google searches, which is hit and miss.  Thank you

@NewbieBAT the .NET documentation Custom TimeSpan format strings is very well explained, problem is it's written for C#. It will be hard to find .NET documentations written for PowerShell (at least written by Microsoft).

Thank you - I'm conversant in C#.  I'll check it out.  I also found online Powershell documentation.  I hate reading tech manuals on a browser :(
